# How to create and read directories in Hadoop - Mapreduce Job working directory

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I want to create a directory inside the working directory of a MapReduce job in Hadoop.

For example by using:
             File setupFolder = new File(setupFolderName);
        setupFolder.mkdirs();

in my mapper class to write some intermediate files in it. Is it the right way to do it?.

Also after completion of the job how will I access this directory again if I wish so?

Please advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using java, you can override the `setup` method and open the file handler there ( and close it in `cleanup` ) . This handle will be available to all mappers.

I am assuming that you are not writing all the map output here but some debug/stats. With this handler you can read and write as it is show in this example ( http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HadoopDfsReadWriteExample )

if you want to read the whole directory, check out this example https://sites.google.com/site/hadoopandhive/home/how-to-read-all-files-in-a-directory-in-hdfs-using-hadoop-filesystem-api

remember that you will not be able to depend on the the order of data written to the files.

Answer (score 2):

You can override setupReduce() in reducer class, use mkdirs() to create folder and use create() to create file for outputstream.

```
@Override
    protected void setupReduce(Context context) throws IOException {
        Configuration conf = context.getConfiguration();
        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
        fs.mkdirs(new Path("your_path_here"));
    }
```